# Do clothes influence behavior

Tags: behavior

I was just curious that does clothes influence behavior? I feel that if I wear sports wear I feel more joyful and energetic.

Have any studies been done on it?

Comment: Related: [What personality traits does sexy and revealing clothing correlate with?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5497/7001)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Have you found any sources of information in your research?